# Should I add a tag to a question after the answer indicates that something, identified by the tag, is related with the question?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, if someone asks this question:

> I'm getting an error doing X. Why?

A possible answer could be:

> You need to do Y to avoid getting this error.

If Y is a technique or tool and if Y has a tag, should I edit the question to add the [y](/questions/tagged/y) tag? **It seems correct** because specialists in [y](/questions/tagged/y) will be able to find the question and add more useful information.

However, I can see two issues:

1. If [a](/questions/tagged/a) or [b](/questions/tagged/b) is also a possible solution, the question will have many distinct tags.

**Example**

Question:

> My PC is freezing. What should I do?

Answer 1:

> You need to run an anti-virus to remove malwares.

Answer 2:

> Your PC may be overheated. Check if your fan is working correctly.

So, in this case, should I add [anti-virus](/questions/tagged/anti-virus) + [cooling](/questions/tagged/cooling) to the question?

2. If the question is marked with [y](/questions/tagged/y), the OP will look a bit dumb for asking something that is quite obvious if you see the tag.

**Example**

Question:

> What series is it?

Answer:

> This is "Game of Thrones".

Adding a [game-of-thrones](/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) tag would make the OP to look dumb.

Another example for this would be:

Question:

> How can I securely store an user password?

Answer:

> You should hash the password before storing it.

In this case, should I add the [hash](/questions/tagged/hash) tag?

So, how should I proceed? Is there a generic guidance?

Comment: I was always under the impression that tags should be based on the question, not the answer... that question goes against that concept entirely.

Comment: I prefer to see tags that represent the Q&A rather than just the question that it can be considered the evolution of.  I think it is fine to add tags that result from accepted and/or highly upvoted answers because they will help answers to be found by later searches.